# How do I create a (dockerized) Elasticsearch index using a python script running in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to index a containerized Elasticsearch db using the Python client https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py called from a script (running in a container too).

By looking at existing pieces of code, it seems that `docker-compose` is a useful tool to use for my purpose. My dir structure is

```
docker-compose.yml
indexer/
- Dockerfile
- indexer.py
- requirements.txt
elasticsearch/
- Dockerfile
```

My `docker-compose.yml` reads

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch/
    ports: 
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - deploy_network
    container_name: elasticsearch

  indexer:
    build: indexer/
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - deploy_network
    container_name: indexer
  
networks:
  deploy_network:
    driver: bridge
```

`indexer.py` reads

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
    
es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{"host":'elasticsearch'}]) # what should I put here?

actions = [
    {
    '_index' : 'test',
    '_type' : 'content',
    '_id' : str(item['id']),
    '_source' : item,
    }
for item in [{'id': 1, 'foo': 'bar'}, {'id': 2, 'foo': 'spam'}]
]
    
# create index
print("Indexing Elasticsearch db... (please hold on)")
bulk(es, actions)
print("...done indexing :-)")
```

The Dockerfile for the elasticsearch service is

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.1.3
EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

and that for the indexer is

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "indexer.py" ]
```

with `requirements.txt` containing only `elasticsearch` to be downloaded with pip.

Running with `docker-compose run indexer` gives me the error message at https://pastebin.com/6U8maxGX (`ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`).
elasticsearch is up as far as I can see with `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'` or by running `docker ps -a`.

How can I modify my `docker-compose.yml` or `indexer.py` to solve the problem?

P.S. A (working) version (informed by the answers below) of the code can be found here, for completeness' sake: https://github.com/davidefiocco/dockerized-elasticsearch-indexer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is a synchronisation bug: `elasticsearch` hasn't fully started when `indexer` tries to connect to it. You'll have to add some retry logic which makes sure that `elasticsearch` is up and running before you try to run queries against it. Something like running `es.ping()` in a loop until it succeeds with an exponential backoff should do the trick.

UPDATE: The Docker [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) instruction can be used to achieve a similar result (i.e. make sure that `elasticsearch` is up and running before trying to run queries against it).

Comment: OK! Following your suggestion, adding `import time` and `time.sleep(12)` in my `indexer.py` did it. Thanks Mihai! The code at https://github.com/davidefiocco/dockerized-elasticsearch-indexer is working for me.

Comment: Also, for reference, this can be useful: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 2):

Making more explicit @Mihai_Todor update, we could use `HEALTHCHECK` (docker 1.12+), for instance with a command like:

```
curl -fsSL "http://$(hostname --ip-address):9200/_cat/health?h=status" | grep -E '^green'
```

To answer this question using using `HEALTHCHECK`:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -fsSL "http://$(hostname --ip-address):9200/_cat/health?h=status" | grep -E '^green'

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "indexer.py" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `retry` to make sure Elasticsearch is ready to accept connections:

```
from retrying import retry

client = Elasticsearch()


class IndexerService:

    @staticmethod
    @retry(wait_exponential_multiplier=500, wait_exponential_max=100000)
    def init():
        MyDocumentIndex.init()

# Here we will wait until ES is ready, or 100 sec passed.
IndexerService.init()
```

It tries in 500 ms, 1 sec, 2 sec, 4 sec until 100 sec.

Reference: https://github.com/rholder/retrying